# Is it possible to directly call a function defined in the annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

I am a Java beginner and I am studying annotations.

Below is my code.

```java
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyRuntimeAnnotation {
    String value() default "default value";
}

----

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.value()); // Error
    }
}

@MyRuntimeAnnotation
class A{
    public void test() {System.out.println("A");}
}
```

I've tried to speculate why my code is producing an error for the following reasons. From reading multiple articles, it's said that the annotation processor can only generate new source files but not modify existing files.

Based on my assumptions:

`@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)` -> Disappears at compile time
`@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)` -> Doesn't load at runtime
`@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` -> Loads at runtime

From the compiler's perspective, `a.value()` is just a method that is not defined in B. So, if I want to use a Runtime annotation, is the only option to extract information using reflection?

Comment: Yes, you need reflection to access annotations. I'm not sure why you would expect `a.value()` to work. Annotating a class doesn't magically inject instance methods into it.

Comment: What might be confusing is that an annotation is defined with `@interface`, so you might think that it's just like an interface - but it is really not. When you annotate a class, then the class does not implement the methods of the annotation, just like it would with an interface.

Comment: Oh, right. I thought it worked like an interface. It also looks similar to Python's decorators, which adds to the confusion. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code, the issue you're facing is due to the fact that you're trying to call the method `value()` on an instance of class `A`. However, `value()` is not a method of class `A`; it's a method of the annotation `@MyRuntimeAnnotation`.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        
        Class<?> aClass = a.getClass();
        MyRuntimeAnnotation annotation = aClass.getAnnotation(MyRuntimeAnnotation.class);
        
        if (annotation != null) {
            String value = annotation.value();
            System.out.println("Annotation value: " + value);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Annotation not found");
        }
    }
}

@MyRuntimeAnnotation
class A {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

This code uses reflection to access the annotation on class `A` and retrieve the value of the annotation's `value` element.

When you want to access values from runtime annotations, you generally use reflection to retrieve those values.